# Android (eclipse) PNG transparency shown as black (with pic examples)

Tags: android, eclipse, image, png, transparency

I have problems making transparent PNGs look transparent in android/eclipse.

I have this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/someid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/theimage" />
```

The XML graphical layout show the image transparency as BLACK when using this image in the imageview:

http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3140/ehqd3yhm_png.htm

If I use the following image the transparency is shown fine:

http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3140/dc5aco6n_png.htm

You will see image icons as transparent infront of a windows desktop wallpaper. You may also verify the images by hand to see that they infact both are transparent.

Is this a bug or what is going on? I am not able to create a transparent PNG that will show in eclipse/android. So I took the second image from the web to show you...

EDIT: I need to make lots of images transparent, currenty I am using irfanview. What other program would suit?

**EDIT2:**

One additional thing to note is I put

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

into my manifest because I want white theme instead of black. Don't know if that has any implications.

The whole XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beleg_imagegesperrt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_schloss_zu"/>

    <!-- this is the imageview I test with, i added  android:background="#FF0000" but does not help -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beleg_imageabgeschlossen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickBarauslagen"
        android:src="@drawable/dddd" 
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beleg_imageeinsatzberichtvorhanden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_notizbuch_unselected" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_textbelegid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textbelegid" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_belegid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/belegid" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_textbelegvonbis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textbelegvonbis" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_belegvon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/belegvon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_belegbis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/belegbis" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_textbelegabgeschlossen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textbelegabgeschlossen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_belegabgeschlossen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/belegabgeschlossen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_textbeleggesperrt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textbeleggesperrt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_beleggesperrt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/beleggesperrt" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_textbelegsummestunden"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textbelegsummestunden" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beleg_belegsummestunden"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abstand_liste"
            android:text="@string/belegsummestunden" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Photoshop. Or, if you don't have that GIMP which is free. (http://www.gimp.org)

Comment: Just to let you know, I tried first image you provided and it worked ok on my SGS II.

Comment: Hm has it got to do with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" which i put into my manifest file by chance? What can I do to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***OK
Cofirmed it is a IrfanView bug.***

If I use the IrfanView plugin pngout.dll (thank god this exists) to save the png however (you can select in the save dialog whether to use the plugin), the pngs are not "corrupted".

Who would have thought?

edit: downbload the plugin here http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm (in one of those zip files)

edit2: ok could also be a bug of eclipse. whatever program writes or reads the PNG non-standardconform, that is

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your image is displaying as transparent, but some part of your layout is actually a black background, and since the portion of the image is transparent, the background is showing through.

Try setting the background of the `ImageView` to a certain color and see if it changes.

You can just add this line to your xml in the `ImageView` section:

`android:background="#FF0000"` (red) or some other hex value to see if that shows through.

Can you post the whole xml file?

Edit: I use Paint.net to work with images, it's free and works well for creating transparent backgrounds.

Comment: Hi thank you, I updated my post with the xml code. Note also that I have android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" in my manifest (don't know if that has something to do with the problem, because the default theme is black too...). Your suggestion does not help unfortunately. Will paint.net do batch convert to transparent png? In irfanview I can just click click click the transparent color in rapid succession and process a lot of images like that.

Comment: update: I tried the second image now too. Here the red color is displayed in the transparent areas of the PNG. Just not with the first image :( I mean they are both transparent png images. I don't get it.

Comment: paint.net works, just tested it, but I need to make transparent PNGs and lots of them...this is not going to be fun

Comment: Does this only happen with that one image? If so, is it possible that you happened to save that image without its alpha channel? For converting to transparent pings (assuming you mean the background) using paint.net you can just select the magic wand and click the background color, then press delete. This is assuming the background is all one color.

Answer (score 0):

Try using null for the background for your image view in the xml layout.

```
android:background="@null"
```